# Cannot get PostgreSQL JDBC working with PySpark in Spark environment

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, jdbc

I wanted to interact with a postgresql database in a remote linux machine. Postgres is 12 and Linux is openjdk 1.8.0_402. To get the postgresql JDBC, I went to https://jdbc.postgresql.org/download/ and downloaded postgresql-42.7.2.jar.

Tried to use below Python script to pull some quick data from the pg database:

```
# Import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

# Create a SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("PostgresToSparkDataframe") \
    .config("spark.driver.extraClassPath", "/usr/share/java/postgresql-jdbc/postgresql-42.7.2.jar") \
    .getOrCreate()

# Define PostgreSQL connection details
jdbcUrl = "jdbc:postgresql://XX.XX.XX.XX:5432/daname"
dbProperties = {
    "user": "username",
    "password": "userpsw",
    "driver": "org.postgresql.Driver"
}

# Read data into Spark DataFrame
df = spark.read.jdbc(url=jdbcUrl, table="schemaname.tablename", properties=dbProperties)

# Show the DataFrame
df.show()
```

But kept getting the error, suggesting the jdbc is not correct??

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o90.jdbc.
: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.postgresql.Driver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:387)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    ......
```

For a quick testing, I tried pulling data from that table in spark-shell and it was straightforward.

I also tried postgresql-42.6.1.jar and postgresql-42.3.8.jar, and none of them worked for me.

Feels like there is something else I missed out ...

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you have the permission to read the JDBC driver file, you can check it like bellow:

```
user@server01:~ # ls -l /usr/share/java/postgresql-jdbc/postgresql-42.7.2.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1089136  2月 20 23:22 /usr/share/java/postgresql-jdbc/postgresql-42.7.2.jar
user@server01:~ # jar tvf /usr/share/java/postgresql-jdbc/postgresql-42.7.2.jar|grep org.postgresql.Driver
   988 Fri Feb 01 00:00:00 CST 1980 org/postgresql/Driver$1.class
  3721 Fri Feb 01 00:00:00 CST 1980 org/postgresql/Driver$ConnectThread.class
 19511 Fri Feb 01 00:00:00 CST 1980 org/postgresql/Driver.class
```

if you don't have read permission, you can just run **chmod +r /usr/share/java/postgresql-jdbc/postgresql-42.7.2.jar** as root to get it.

Another thing you should be aware, you should use **python** to run the program, not the **pyspark** or **spark-submit**.